# black screen with clayton@clayton-desktop:~$ in the top left corner. I have no idea what to do

Tags: boot

I am a long term but ICT challenged ubuntu user. My stable desktop crashed a few weeks ago while i was on the interweb and ever since boots to black screen with clayton@clayton-desktop:~$ and a non-blinking cursor in the top left corner. How do I get ubuntu and my files back? Currently running 12.04 (from memory, or maybe 12.10).
Any help would be appreciated

P.S. i have looked through many of the FAQ's without any joy including the ones suggested here which seem to be off topic as they relate to installs not functioning systems.

Comment: **First**, if you could answer some questions, it would be easier to determine what to do. 1 - What were you doing when the system crashed? 2 - Can you type anything after **"clayton@clayton-desktop:~$"** ?

Comment: was on the internet. yes i can type after "clayton@clayton-desktop:~$" Cheers Clayton

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to input text, try typing `startx` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This might give you a GUI.

Comment: startx gave me : "X: user not authorised to run the X server, aborting.""X10: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server":0" after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining."

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know. Try "sudo startx" but other than that I don't know.

Comment: Thanks. This gave me a fatal server error message and directed me to X.org support.

Comment: problem now semi sorted. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use unity try type `gdm` and hit enter.
If you use kde try `kdm`. Gui should appear.